# git shows delete in status, but they're not

Tags: git

I've gotten myself into a pickle.

I have .dat files on-disk, and through a twisted and obviously incorrect git procedural sequence, git thinks I've deleted the files. The state of the files is as I want (present), but git status still thinks they're deleted.

I've tried doing "git checkout -- file", "git add file", "git checkout -- file" and nothing seems to touch the status.  I don't want to use "git rm" because I really don't want the files removed from either the disk or the cache...the repo just seems confused.

How do I get the repo back into sanity?

Here's a listing:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    SHAP5-2.2-20140304T1200.CO2.dat
        deleted:    SHAP5-2.2-20140304T1200.H2O.dat
        deleted:    SHAP5-2.2-20140304T1300.CO2.dat
        deleted:    SHAP5-2.2-20140304T2300.CO2.dat
        deleted:    SHAP5-2.2-20140304T2300.H2O.dat

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use `git reset -- <file>` to unstage the deleted files:

```
git reset -- SHAP5-2.2-20140304T1200.CO2.dat
```

Then do `git checkout -- <file>` to restore the deleted files into your working directory from the index:

```
git checkout -- SHAP5-2.2-20140304T1200.CO2.dat
```

Repeat this procedure for all 5 files and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Note that the files were still present, so no deletion actually occurred.  This does seem to be clearing out the weirdness. :)